# How to form regular expression that filters out the words that start with == and end with ==?

Tags: java, regex

I want to filter out all the words that start out with `==` and also end in `==`, for example `==Hello==`, but I don't want words such as `===Bye===` to be part of such a matching,

I am using the following regex but it doesn't return the results I am looking for: `==(.*?)==`, what mistake am I doing in formulating the regex?

Answer (score 3):

`==(.*?)==` still matches `===Bye===`.  You need to check specifically that there is no preceding or following `=`.  You also need to make sure that no `=` are captured, so `.*` is not going to work.  Use `[^=]`.

```
(?<!=)==([^=]*)==(?!=)
```

http://rubular.com/r/bWpBPf3QXZ

Comment: I executed this regex on the following string = "===[[Guatemala]]=== * [[Flores (Guatemala)]] - a city ===[[Indonesia]]=== * [[Flores (Indonesia)]] - an island ===[[Portugal]]=== * [[Flores (Azores)]] - an island in the [[Azores]] ===[[Uruguay]]=== * [[Flores (Uruguay)]] - a department"; it still doesn't work

Comment: This returns the result as - ===[[Guatemala]]===
===[[Indonesia]]===
===[[Portugal]]===
===[[Uruguay]]===

Comment: What if I want to remove the leading and trailing underscores in a string with an empty character and leave the underscores that occur between characters for instance I want _Get_In as Get_In? how to do this?

Comment: @AnkitSablok that sounds like a separate quesiton

Comment: I am trying to accomplish some task that is related to this one, if you can help would be great :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([^=]|^)==([^=]+)==([^=]|$)
```

It handles the match occurring at the beginning or end of the given String as well.

Comment: What is meant by the match occurring at the beginning or end of the given string?

Comment: The |^ and |$ mean that this will match, for example "==STR==" as well as "blah==STR==blah". This was not really a comment toward the other answers, but just a comment on why those were in the regex.

Comment: I don't want this. I guess that is why I am getting bad result, what if I want to remove this?

Comment: @AnkitSablok If you don't want matches at the beginning of your String, remove the "|^" and if you don't want matches at the end of your String, remove the "|$"

Comment: What if I want to remove the leading and trailing underscores in a string with an empty character and leave the underscores that occur between characters for instance I want ___Get_In__ as Get_In? how to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<!=)==\K[^=]+(?===)(?!===)
```

See demo **[here](http://regexr.com?37cpe)**.